How to fix Flutter Webview library is not working
I'm using Flutter's webview_flutter package, but it's not working. My pubspec.yaml file is configured as follows:
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
webview_flutter: ^4.0.1
After running flutter pub get, I encounter the following issues in my code:
The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'.
Undefined name 'JavascriptMode'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
Unused import: 'package
/webview_flutter.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'ForYou WebView',
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: MyHomePage(),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('ForYou WebView'),
            ),
            body: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
        );
    }
}```

Additional Information:

I’ve tried other plugins, and while some worked without issues in the code, none worked in the emulator—they just keep loading.
I’ve attempted to use WebView in Flutter, but nothing has worked so far.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!


Hey, this probably isn't the issue, but I've had this happen numorous times on other packages and I always had to run flutter pub get and flutter clean and most importantly restart Android Studio (or whatever software you use), usually after this it'll be defined :)

You've imported a relatively fresh version of the webview_flutter package(^4.0.1) but trying to use the old API(for versions below 4.0.0). So what you need to do is either downgrade the version in pubspec.yaml, to make your code work, or use the new API. I recommend the second way:

Import the package: import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

Define the controller, and pass it to a WebViewWidget
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://google.com'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView Example'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}




thanks a lot for the information tried it and still having issues , i'm not a mobile app dev , that's why i'm facing these errors , if you can only kindly give me the full code if it not a bother to you , i would appreciate that a lot .

@HusseinAlzide I've edited my answer, added a code example, because comments are limited by length.
